# Lua delete from playlist - VLC Plugin

Tags: lua, wait, vlc

I try to delete the current playing file in playlist. I have some plugin in Lua to do that but the file is stil in use at this time.

Therefore I need a short wait in my script.

```
function nexttrack()
   vlc.playlist.delete(itemId)
   vlc.playlist.next()
   delete()
end

function delete()
   os.remove(filename) -- do nothing at this time
end
```

I have try os.execute(sleep 1) and os.execute(ping ....) but generally Vlc crashed when I try to run os.execute!

When I run delete() from a massagebox the file will get deleted.

Did somebody have a tip to get it working

Answer (score 0):

You could simulate a busy wait with [os.time](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-os.time) and a loop.

For a sleep/wait of the OS scheduler, Lua 5.1 (which normal builds of VLC use) standard libraries don't have a function.

In case of VLC with [LuaJIT](http://luajit.org/) you would have the [ffi library](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_tutorial.html) which offers access to DLL functions, system libraries with **sleep** included.

Taking a look at the [VLC Lua API](http://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/share/lua/README.txt), **misc.mdate** and **misc.mwait** could be what you're searching for.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it with a loop who test/wait for changes in my ItenId value (TrackID in Vlc Playlist)!

```
function nexttrack()
   vlc.playlist.delete(itemId)
   vlc.playlist.next()
   while probe() == itemId
   do
       vlc.msg.info("wait")
   end   
   close()
   os.remove(filename)
end
```